# How do broadcast receivers work in android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

When a broadcast is received, is the receiver ran in a different thread, or are the variable put onto the stack, the pointer position changed to the receiver code, and then the code of the receiver is ran?

Answer (score 0):

> is the receiver ran in a different thread

Objects are not "run" in Java. *Methods* are run.

The `onReceive()` method of a `BroadcastReceiver` is called on the main application thread.

> or are the variable put onto the stack, the pointer position changed to the receiver code, and then the code of the receiver is ran?

The framework calls the `onReceive()` method when a broadcast is sent out that matches the receiver's `<intent-filter>` or `IntentFilter`. Precisely what that method call converts into, in terms of Dalvik bytecode or ART compiled code, is undocumented.